# Monero Wallet RPC: tx_blob is always empty

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, stagenet

I'm attempting to create a transaction for broadcast later but `tx_blob` always returns empty. `tx_metadata` is populated so I attempted to relay that at: https://monero-stagenet.exan.tech/rawtx but it was rejected.

> The data does not appear to be signed raw tx! Data prefix: 0xffffffd3]z0xffffffef~0xffffffb90xffffffefn0xffffffbd0xffffffeb^0xffffff9c0xffffffeb0xffffffde0xffffffda0xffffffeb^0xfffffff80xffffffeb0xffffffde0xffffff9f

Request:

```
{
  "params": {
    "unlock_time": 0,
    "ring_size": 7,
    "priority": 1,
    "mixin": 7,
    "get_tx_metadata": true,
    "get_tx_key": true,
    "get_tx_hex ": true,
    "do_not_relay": true,
    "destinations": [
      {
        "amount": 1000000000000,
        "address": "56Wfz6VXwNJcek5fmSGV6P2Li5oSDzJvKf3rkfxue1Qd67Y18MPmKwTeR656bLqmXvHPFJ1vdsk6K4AzAuPp6yJmVSVqyqF"
      }
    ]
  },
  "method": "transfer",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 0
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "amount": 1000000000000,
    "fee": 13564070000,
    "multisig_txset": "",
    "unsigned_txset": "",
    "tx_blob": "",
    "tx_hash": "bc8bb62afca7bd35e8df7a9b8da71b33164a123d8b81b97413ea835e65908a3f",
    "tx_key": "8a607569d6d69e5888ba43bbb2020dd6fa5ba323393aba9eabff852ec45aea0b",
    "tx_metadata": "011673657269616c697a6174696f6e3a3a617263686976650000000103000001020000000101000000010300000..."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `relay_tx` method, you're supposed to pass the `tx_metadata` to it.

See the method [here](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#relay_tx).

I can confirm it works fine.

Comment: So it appears that the transaction explorers are broken as they cannot relay transactions but the method you described works.

Comment: It is not a transaction explorers job to relay transactions. Relaying is performed by the daemons.

Comment: They have a feature that doesn't work. I can relay from my own daemon and not theirs.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, `tx_blob` is only returned if you relayed the tx from `transfer`.

If you wish to relay later, you use `relay_tx` passing in your returned `tx_metadata` from `transfer`.

https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#relay_tx

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're not getting tx_blob back is that it is only returned if you set get_tx_hex to true. You did not, you set "get_tx_hex " with a space to true.

Comment: Whilst the json posted has an extraneous space, the docs are clear that you only get a blob after sending. "get_tx_hex - boolean; Return the transaction as hex string after sending (Defaults to false)"

Comment: Send a patch for the docs then. I tried it, and it does what I said. I used transfer_split btw, transfer is obsolete.

Comment: How did you broadcast tx_blob? relay_tx docs are specifying tx_metadata as input parameter, not tx_blob. OP is asking how to create tx and send later.